# Need help on SQL Server 2008 programming

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL Server 2008 programming and trying to create a procedure.

Well, the requirement is *'The procedure returns data either based on  the input parameter OR if no input data is given-it should do a default select and return all data qualifying'*

I tried out with something like this-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_sampletestproc]
   (@testid int)
AS
BEGIN         
   SET NOCOUNT OFF;  ----I worked with Oracle PL/SQL and so do we need for mandatory this declarations
```

Here, I need to put a check that if the input `testid` has a value or not. If it exists, we have one case with a select or we do a default select.

Also, I am putting a direct `SELECT` with no joins on tables. How would I `JOIN` the tables along with `OUTER JOINS` because a `testid` may or may not have an insurance? I mean syntactically - syntax is quite different in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
    T.TESTID, T.NAME, TI.INSURENAME 
FROM 
    testinsured ti, test t, testinsuredHistory tih
WHERE
    t.testid = ti.testid  -----This entry may be there or not IN THE testinsured TABLE
    AND tih.testinsuredid = ti.testinsuredid --A testid might have 2 Insurers whose history is stored here.
    AND TIH.STARTDATE IS NOT NULL
    AND TIH.ENDDATE IS NOT NULL     --TO CHECK ACTIVE DATES FOR COVERAGE
```

Also, I want to do a group by on `testid` so that the name comes once but the `InsuredPlanname` comes accordingly once, twice as many as each `Testid` has.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (@testid is not null)
begin
    /* ... */
end
else 
begin
    SELECT T.TESTID,T.NAME,TI.INSURENAME 
    FROM test t 
    left outer join testinsured ti on t.testid = ti.testid -----This entry may be there or not IN THE testinsured TABLE
    left outer join testinsuredHistory tih on ti.testinsuredid = tih.testinsuredid --A testid might have 2 Insurers whose history is stored here.
    where TIH.STARTDATE IS NOT null AND TIH.ENDDATE IS NOT NULL
    /* group by ... */
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs. But,i found if I do group by on `testid`-then I cannot get values of `t.name,ti.username`.

Comment: So, can anyone please help me with the code and syntax of how to display for each `testid` -> multiple rows using `group by`.

Comment: You need to group by the columns you are going to select that are not going to be contained in an aggregate function, i.e. `group by t.name, ti.username`, with any other column you need as well - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your inputs. But I wanted to say that the first solution did not work(which surprised me too) because the stored procedure expects an input test_id under any case.If I passed NULL,O-still error was the same.            Can anyone guide me on how to paste an image(screen print) to explain my further doubts.Please help me.